# How to load child route by default in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

At the start of application i want to load child route.

Right now URLcome but respective component not load on that section but when again hit the actual URL it comes.

like route configure is

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'a', component: AComponent,
         children:[
                   { path:'x',component:AXcomponent }
                   ]
        },
        { path: 'b', component: bComponent, }
]
```

Now i want to load path `a/x` how i will load at the start of page ?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, but you should be able to use `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/a/b', pathMatch: 'full' },` so that your empty path ' ' redirects to '/a/b' and then loads the corresponding component.

Comment: it not working url is set but first time component not loaded but when hit direct url then its loaded

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Add empty path routes as redirect automatically

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: 'a',
        pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:'',
                redirectTo: 'x',
                pathMatch: 'full' 
            },
            {
                path:'x',
                component: AXcomponent 
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        path: 'b',
        component: bComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: How would it be if the child route contains an outlet?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa Have you got any idea for outlet scenario  ?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar concern. What if I want to see a path instead of living it blank. In my case I have an authentication module, that has many components (register, login ...). I would like to see in my page url www.mywebpage.com/authentication/login. With @SantanuBiswas approach I wouldn't be able to see login in the url. Any workaround to this similar concern? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is no good if your child route contains an outlet.

For example I am displaying an 'order' by ID and using a named outlet 'detail' for the summary as well as other panels.

```
/orders/5000001/(detail:summary)
/orders/5000001/(detail:edit)
```

Because these URLS are so ugly I also wanted the following two to redirect:

```
/orders/5000001           =>    /orders/5000001/(detail:summary)
/orders/5000001/summary   =>    /orders/5000001/(detail:summary)
```

So I tried a componentless redirect in the child:

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '(detail:summary)' }
```

This fails because a 'redirectTo' needs to be absolute (I'm sure there's a complex technical reason for this). So then I tried this:

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/order/:id/(detail:summary)' }
```

And that fails because `:id` is not a named variable in the context of the child.

So in the end I figured this out:

```
 children: [

     { path: ':id', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/orders/:id/(detail:summary)' },
     { path: ':id/summary', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/orders/:id/(detail:summary)' },
     {
         // this goes in the main router outlet
         path: ':id', component: OrderFulldetailsComponent,

         children: [

             { path: 'summary', component: OrderSummaryComponent, outlet: 'detail' },
             { path: 'edit', component: OrderEditComponent, outlet: 'detail' }
         ]
     }
 ]
```

Note it is important to do `pathMatch: 'full'` on `path: ':id'` or it will match when you hit `/:id/(detail:summary)` and go nowhere.